# Sending 'const char *' to parameter of type 'const uint8_t *' error

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-warnings

Am coding an iOS App, in which I have declared a string constant in a Constants file :

```
NSString * const kHeader = @"name,age,gender";
```

and in Constants.h

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const kHeader;
```

and am attempting to write this string to NSOutput stream in a ViewController class as:

[outputStream write : [kHeader UTF8String] maxLength : [kHeader length]];

This is showing a compiler warning :
**Sending 'const char *' to parameter of type 'const uint8_t *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign**

What does this mean? How do I resolve this? Please help. Googl'ing didn't generate much useful result.

Comment: It means `UTF8String` is signed, and the output stream is expecting an unsigned value.  Just add a cast to silence the warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the signed/unsigned pointer warning, your code can actually be *wrong*.
`[kHeader length]` returns the number of Unicode characters in the string, and this
can be different from the number of UTF-8 bytes returned by `[kHeader UTF8String]`.

For example, `@"€"` has one Unicode character, but 3 UTF-8 bytes.

So you should replace that by

```
const char *utf8string = [kHeader UTF8String];
[outputStream write:(const uint8_t *)utf8string maxLength:strlen(utf8string)];
```

or alternatively

```
NSData *data = [kHeader dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
```

Comment: Let me try this & get back. what you are saying makes a lot of sense. Thank you.